# Confused with an SQL query

Tags: sql, database

Let's assume we have a database for a chat application:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (uid int PRIMARY KEY, name text, phone text );

CREATE TABLE Messages (recipient int REFERENCES Users(uid), sender int 
REFERENCES Users(uid), time timestamp NOT NULL, message text NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (recipient, sender, time));
```

I want to find all the messages that have been sent between at least two different pairs of users. For instance, if message "Hello" has been sent from User 1
to User 2 and from User 75 to User 83 as well then it must be shown to the result. However, if it has been sent only between User 1 and User 2 then it shouldn't be shown to the result.

I consider grouping all the messages that appear at least two times as follows:

```
SELECT message 
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY message 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, this won't help since the same pair of users might have sent the same message over and over again. Can I group by sender, recipient and message at the same time? If yes, what is this gonna give me as a result?

In addition, is there a way that I could easily fill these two tables with random values and practise queries by myself in order to check them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am a beginner and don't know in which environment and how exactly I should build my database. So, I am just trying to solve this theoritically.

Comment: @MJ13 regardless of how generic your SQL statement might be, you'd still need a SQL database to run the queries. And there are some subtle differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea first start by grouping user1, user2, & message. This gives you a unique message for every pair:

```
SELECT case when recipient > sender then recipient else sender end user1,
       case when recipient > sender then sender else recipient end user2,
       message 
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY user1, user2, message
```

Then from that result group by Message and return only count greater than 1. You can use a nested query to do this:

```
SELECT message, COUNT(message) 
FROM (SELECT case when recipient > sender then recipient else sender end user1,
            case when recipient > sender then sender else recipient end user2,
            message 
     FROM Messages 
     GROUP BY user1, user2, message) PairMessages 
GROUP BY message 
HAVING COUNT(message) > 1
```

Maybe start with this as a test:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1,'john',1111111111)
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2,'paul',2222222222)
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (75,'george',7575757575)
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (83,'ringo',8383838383)
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (2,1,GETDATE(),'Yesterday')
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (1,2,GETDATE(),'hello')
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (75,83,GETDATE(),'yellow')
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (75,83,GETDATE(),'hello')
```

You should be able to get hello as your message sent between more than 1 pair of users.

Edit: I updated the above with the correct answer to show that each pair of users is unique for each message. Also, it may be a good idea to create a groupID for every pair of users. Then you can add as many users as you want to that groupID. See here for an idea: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbc2e2/3

Comment: I think if I run the following SQL code I get the desired answer:                                                         
                                                                                                               `SELECT message, COUNT(message)                                                         FROM (SELECT sender, recipient, message 
             FROM Messages 
             GROUP BY sender, recipient, message) as PairMessages         
GROUP BY message
HAVING COUNT(message) > 1`

Comment: Yea it should work since you are grouping. Also, actually I did get the query to work on sqlfiddle (i changed it to use MSSQL Server rather than MySQL). Look here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/662bb/4

Comment: Unfortunately, don't think this works if the pair of users sent the same message two times but the user that is the sender the first time is the recipient the second time. In that case it shouldn't count since it's not a different pair but it seems that is counts. Check the example. The message 'Yesterday' shouldn't be counted.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd40c3/1

Comment: Good call! Did you figure out your solution? I feel like the best way is to a create a groupID column in the messages table which would represent a pair of users (or a chat session). Then group by that instead of sender, recip. A quick solution is to use the numerical order of a pair of users as the unique identifier: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd40c3/27

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hadn't figured it out. I think your solution is pretty good and easy to understand. If u have the time please edit your answer and write down the code for these two solutions that you mentioned in order to accept your answer since it solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for MySql:

```
SELECT message 
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY message 
HAVING 
  COUNT(distinct least(recipient, sender), greatest(recipient, sender)) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sQjrXXPe9QjD7xDxJVQfoa/1).

Comment: What is your dbms?

Comment: It works. My mistake. I am just not familiar with these expressions. Just came up with this code :                                                                                             
`SELECT message  FROM (SELECT sender, recipient, message FROM Messages GROUP BY sender, recipient, message) as PairMessages GROUP BY message HAVING COUNT(message) > 1`                                                                                          Think it works

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the following query:

```
select message, count(*)
from Messages
group by message
HAVING COUNT(distinct least(recipient, sender), greatest(recipient, sender)) > 1
```

This improves on forpas's query by adding the number of times that message was used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!How can I write that without using the words "least" and "greatest"? (with if/else statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` for the filtering:

```
SELECT m.message 
FROM Messages m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Messages m2
              WHERE m2.message = m.message AND
                    m2.recipient NOT IN (m.recipient, m.sender) AND
                    m2.sender NOT IN (m.recipient, m.sender)
             )       
GROUP BY m.message ;
```

The `EXISTS` checks that another row with the same message has a different pair of users.

Comment: Which attributes does "SELECT 1" actually sellect?

Comment: @MJ13 . . . It selects the constant value `1`.

Comment: Could this query be solved alternatively as I mentioned? By grouping sender, recipient and message at the same time?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work since it accepts only pairs that have not even one user in common. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd40c3/2